# Can I have more than one PS3 savegame in Grand Theft Auto 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My brother and I both want to play GTA V with different save files.

How can I do that? Is it possible to have multiple saves? Can I do this with different PS3 accounts?

Comment: Yeah, different accounts should work, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like 5pike confirm, login using another account do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

You can save manually by choosing the phone(<kbd>UP</kbd> on the *D-Pad*) and then chosing the save function.

To load, go to pause menu, game, load game

You have up to 15 save slots.  You also have the option to copy a saved game to another slot.

Comment: that was not my question

Answer (score 0):

By saving in one of the 15 save slots available, you can branch your gameplay from those designated areas, e.g. saving your game in slot 1 & copying that same save in slot 2 for your brother to create his own experience.

A drawback may be that your progress is currently too far for him to be satisfied but on that slot 2 copy, he should be able to reload a "past" game (that you previously did but now is copied into his data) and carry out missed missions totally separate from your gameplay to catch up.

As far as creating a blank slate for a new instance of the game goes, a sub account on the PS3 may work.